# Map virtual box machine to a drive letter in windows

Tags: virtualbox

How can i map a drive letter to virtual box vm in windows? So for instance, i want a folder `/home/user` in my virtual machine to be mapped to the `x:` drive in windows? The vm is connected via host only networking.

Comment: You could set a folder in your host as the sharing folder and then 'mount' it in the guest os.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use good old network sharing, just as between two real machines?

Answer (score 0):

Samba is the way to go. You are using a linux and you want to map /home/x_user on a windows z: drive :

On virtual linux system, create a user called 'x_user' and execute :

> # smbpasswd -a x_user
>
> # service smb restart

On Windows 7 map the drive using the usual \\ip_of_linux_box method